# Opening multiple html files & outputting to .txt with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, xpath, nokogiri

Just wondering if these two functions are to be done using Nokogiri or via more basic Ruby commands.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require "net/http"
require "uri"

doc = Nokogiri.parse(open("example.html"))

doc.xpath("//meta[@name='author' or @name='Author']/@content").each do |metaauth|
puts "Author: #{metaauth}"
end

doc.xpath("//meta[@name='keywords' or @name='Keywords']/@content").each do |metakey|
puts "Keywords: #{metakey}"
end

etc...
```

Question 1: I'm just trying to parse a directory of .html documents, get the information from the meta html tags, and output the results to a text file if possible. I tried a simple *.html wildcard replacement, but that didn't seem to work (at least not with Nokogiri.parse(open()) maybe it works with ::HTML or ::XML)

Question 2: But more important, is it possible to output all of those meta content outputs into a text file to replace the puts command?

Also forgive me if the code is overly complicated for the simple task being performed, but I'm a little new to Nokogiri / xpath / Ruby.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you have two totally separate questions here: "how do I extract data from HTML?" and "how do I write a text file?" - I suggest you break this down to its separate parts. As it is - the question is too broad.

Comment: Well, the extraction part is okay, it's more accessing multiple files and then writing the output to a text file. Labeled the two questions in the body for clarification, so hopefully that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a code similar.
Please refer to:

```rb
module MyParser
  HTML_FILE_DIR = `your html file dir`
  def self.run(options = {})
    file_list = Dir.entries(HTML_FILE_DIR).reject { |f| f =~ /^\./ }

    result = file_list.map do |file|
      html = File.read("#{HTML_FILE_DIR}/#{file}")
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
      parse_to_hash(doc)
    end
    write_csv(result)
  end

  def self.parse_to_hash(doc)
    array = []
    array << doc.css(`your select conditons`).first.content
    ... #add your selector code css or xpath

    array
  end

  def self.write_csv(result)
    ::CSV.open("`your out put file name`", 'w') do |csv|
      result.each { |row| csv << row }
    end
  end
end

MyParser.run
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying this out, what exactly from my code does into your array << section? Is the second array line required, or could I replace it with one of my existing lines, like "array << doc.xpath("//meta[@name='keywords' or @name='Keywords']/@content").each"? Well, clearly not as that didn't work. Was getting an error: `write_csv': uninitialized constant CSV (NameError) but that seems like a different issue.

Comment: Yes.Please replace `doc.css('.....')` to `doc.xpath('.....')` .  
And CSV class is required csv gem, which is included stardard library.
Add `require 'csv'` at the first line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can output to a file like so:

```
File.open('results.txt','w') do |file|
  file.puts "output"   # See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-puts
end
```

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
authors = doc.xpath("//meta[@name='author' or @name='Author']/@content")
keywrds = doc.xpath("//meta[@name='keywords' or @name='Keywords']/@content")
results = authors.map{ |x| "Author: #{x}"   }.join("\n") +
          keywrds.map{ |x| "Keywords: #{x}" }.join("\n")
File.open('results.txt','w'){ |f| f << results }
```

Comment: Thanks for the second part. I was initially doing the first, but then appending each result via something like:
    'open('a1.txt', 'a') { |f|
    f.puts "\nKeywords: #{metakey}"
    }   
    end' but that works as well. Though I think the combination of analyzing an entire directory + outputting to a plain text file (rather than a csv or something) might be problematic. Might have to make some concessions.

Comment: @tsukugiri With the first option, you can run your entire program inside the block. There's no reason to keep opening and closing the file.